# laravel Auth::user()->with return all not just authenticated user

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

wrong: this return all Users with their persons:

```
$me = Auth::user()->with('persons')->get();
```

correct: this return just the authenticated user with his persons

```
Auth::user()->persons()->get()
```

Model

```
 public function persons(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Person', 'user_id');
    }
```

where is the difference? why first line returns ALL users?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`with` is supposed to be called on a `Builder` object non on a Model instance.

In the first example, you're calling it on a `User` instance, that is like calling:

```
User::with('persons')->get();
```

so Laravel returns all users along with their persons

Note that if you want to load a relation on a single model you can do:

```
$me = Auth::user();
$me->load('persons');
```

Answer (score 2):

The use of `->with()` in query builder is to  [eager load](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) the relation so it loads related models. It ***does not*** return the related models, only ***loads*** them.

One interesting thing to note here is that auth()->user(), return `User` model instance. Hence, when chaining it with `->with('persons')->get()` you're essentially creating a new Query Builder.

```
$user = auth()->user();
// The following line creates new Query for User model
$allUsersWithPersons = $user->with('persons')->get();
// same as following line
$allUsersWithPersons2 = User::with('persons')->get();
```